# Package install inside a module in module base project in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am using a package [nWidart/laravel-modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules). No problem with installing this package but when I want to install [Sentinel package](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/3.0#installation) It need to add *$providers $ $aliases*. where should import this? config/app.php or other?

My folder structure is now

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add package name on composer.json file that's exist in your moduler->user folder
then run on your terminal...

```
composer-update
```

[image]